# How can I use duplicate row names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I wanted to convert the first column in a data frame, but I got the following error.

```
Maindata1 <- data.frame(Maindata[,-1], row.names = Maindata[,1])
```

Error in data.frame(Maindata[, -1], row.names = Maindata[, 1]) :
duplicate row.names: SICON, si Chk1, nothing, PRKDC, FEN1, SMC3, HMGB1, RPA3, DLGAP5, TP53, CHEK1, POLD1, PCNA, TADA3, RAD51, DUT, H2AFX, UNG, APEX2, RRM2, RBBP8, TP73, RAD17, RAD9A, FLJ20516, RAD1, RBL1, XPC, RAD52, MNAT1, MAD2L2, RB1, CHEK2, e12, e14, e13, e24, e3, e23, e15, e5, e11, e10, e26, e27, e33, e17, e20, e16, e22, e4, e18, e34, e6, e25, e19, e30, e8, e29, e32, e9, e7, e28, e2, e1, e21, e31, HUS1, CDC6, CDKN2D, FANCG, BLM, CDC25A, CKS2, ABL1, ATR, ERCC3, GADD45A, E2F3, CCNH, CDK7, CENPE, ATM, BRCA1, JUN, CKS1B

I know that I have duplicate row names in my data set and I want to use duplicate row names. I wanted to solve using the following code.

```
rownames(df) = make.names(Maindata, unique=TRUE)
```

Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("c.932..520..653..377..729..706..972..147..504..764..500..508..638..517..906..510..636..1168..237..35..359..88

How can I use them in my analysis? I want to make a 3D graph using a big data set to see their position in XYZ's direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `make.unique` which will create unique rownames and then remove the first column from the data.

```
rownames(Maindata) <- make.unique(Maindata[[1]])
Maindata <- Maindata[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak!  But I got following problem  "rownames(Maindata) <- make.unique(Maindata[[1]])
Error in make.unique(Maindata[[1]]) : 'names' must be a character vector"

Comment: @BiswajitPodder Use `rownames(Maindata) <- make.unique(as.character(Maindata[[1]]))`